# React Переключение класса другого компонента по нажатию

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать что б у другого компонента таглился какой-то класс ? Приведу пример.

```js
const useState = React.useState;

class RegisteredUser extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isShowNav: false
  };

  render() {
    const isShow = this.state.isShowNav;

    return (
      <div className="user_control">
        <button
          className={
            isShow
              ? "btn_user decor-borders showNavigation"
              : "btn_user decor-borders "
          }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ isShowNav: !isShow })}
        >
          <span className="btn_user__name">Menu </span>
        </button>
        <UserNavigation />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function UserNavigation(props) {
  return (
    <nav className="controls">
      <button className="controls_link" typeof="button">
        Сообщение
      </button>
      <button className="controls_link" typeof="button">
        Профиль
      </button>
      <button className="controls_link" typeof="button">
        Ответы
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
}

function OurApp() {
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <RegisteredUser />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<OurApp />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
#app{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn_user {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 25px 4px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #4b4e4c;
  background-color: #1A1C1B;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 4px #000;
}

.btn_user__name {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff3e0;
}

.controls {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid #4b4e4c;
  z-index: 10;
}

.btn_user.showNavigation + .controls {
  display: flex;
}

.controls.active {
  display: flex;
}

.controls_link {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
}

.controls_link:hover,
.controls_link:focus {
  color: #65D900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

По сути у меня тут выполняется условие CSS свойства  .btn_user.showNavigation + .controls А как достичь результата то б по нажатию на кнопку срабатывал переключатель на компоненте UserNavigation ? То есть по сути мне надо что б у UserNavigation добавлялся класс active.

Comment: передай ему в пропсах значение isActive

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю, как именно. Можно немного более подробнее ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно как-то так, но глупая логика, добавлять классы, удалять классы.

```
class RegisteredUser extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isShowNav: false
  };

  render() {
    const isShow = this.state.isShowNav;

    return (
      <div className="user_control">
        <button
          className={
            isShow
              ? "btn_user decor-borders showNavigation"
              : "btn_user decor-borders "
          }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ isShowNav: !isShow })}
        >
          <span className="btn_user__name">Menu </span>
        </button>
        {isShow && <UserNavigation/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function UserNavigation() {
    return (
      <nav className="controls">
        <button className="controls_link" typeof="button">
          Сообщение
        </button>
        <button className="controls_link" typeof="button">
          Профиль
        </button>
        <button className="controls_link" typeof="button">
          Ответы
        </button>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Намного проще будет, при условии isShow true рендерить что-то или нет. Так как класс можно дописать и в DevTools, пользователь не зарегестрирован, а навигация загружена, просто скрыта, уязвимость на ровном месте.

Comment: Согласен,  а как реализовывать через условие isShow ?

Comment: Спасибо, да, так намного чище смотрится. А ещё вопрос,   return (<div></div>) всегда должно быть ? Компонент всегда должен хоть что-то возвращать? *Просто без этих <div></div> оно не работает

Comment: код использующий html разметку обязательно должен быть вложен в "контейнер" ! Именно поэтому нужен <div></div> аналогом является <React.Fragment>разметка</React.Fragment> в новом реакте можно так <></>

Comment: @BlackStar1991 return (<div></div>) попробуй поставить null и посмотри за реакцией. Тут очень много всего, что бы обойтись без if(isShow) ты можешь в компоненте RegistrateUser добавить тернарник {isShow && <UserNavigation />} Вот тебе самый красивый вариант.